# Copy parts of an SVN repo to another

Tags: svn, copy, synchronization

Is there any tool (or can svnsync do this, I don't think it can) that can copy a specific file or directory from one repo to another (both remote)?

I want to provide a read-only repo for a code library, but only a subset of that library, not the whole thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind getting your hands dirty, you could write a little script that exports the file(s) of the private project and commits the svn-clean-files to your public project.

This way even svn diffs on the public project are possibly albeit that's not the same as the original svn history. But thats good as it's not intended.

Something like this as cron job?

```
#!/bin/bash

EXPDIR=$(mktemp -d /tmp/projectXXXXXX)

svn export --force svn+ssh://USERNAME@yourserver/repository/project/sub/ $EXPDIR/
svn add $EXPDIR/ svn+ssh://USERNAME@publicserver/repository/subpart/
cd $EXPDIR/
svn ci -m "update `date`" $EXPDIR/

#cleanup
rm -rf "/tmp/$EXPDIR"
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I did it slightly differently, by checking out the destination repo first, then force exporting the source into the working copy, then committing, but it achieves the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [externals definitions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) as a solution. Create new repository for a read-only subset of your code library and map it to a project's subfolder.

Comment: Trouble with that is anyone with access to the externals property will be able to use that to access all of the source repo. I want to keep the source private (and actually don't have the ability to change any of its users/permissions), but make a small subset publicly available in a second repo.

Comment: @Jack Sleight, if you can't change any permissions how do you want to restrict access to your read-only repository? I mean even if you find a solution, everyone will still be able to change files in your "private" repository.

Comment: I can set permissions on the destination/public/read-only repo, just not on the private one which has no public access.

Answer (score 1):

While @initall's solution is viable, you'd loose history info etc. I'd advocate using svnsync as you suggested yourself.

Since 1.5 svnsync is capable of syncing just a sub tree of the source repo, therefore I'd say it's a cleaner solution and you would be able to have different access rights on each repo. See the [repository replication](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication) section in the svn manual for details.

Comment: +1 This is a more pure Subversion solution than the hack that initall is suggesting.